# Process finished with exit code 1 after Hibernate query on abstract class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement a Jpa Repository for an Entity that's derived from an abstract class.

The base, abstract class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseProduct {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String brand;
    private int price;
    private int availability;
    private String description;
    //constructors getters and setters omitted
}
```

The derived class:

```
@Entity
public class Product extends BaseProduct {
//constructors omitted
}
```

The JpaRepository extension:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long > {
}
```

Where it breaks:

```
@Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

        return (args) -> {

            ProductInfo p1 = new ProductInfo("Hook1", "lorem", 2, 50, "desc");

            ProductInfo p2 = new ProductInfo("Hook2", "lorem", 2, 50, "desc");

            Product b1 = new Product(p1);
            productRepository.save(b1);

            productRepository.save(new Product(p2));


            productRepository.findAll().forEach(product -> log.info(product.getName()));
        };
```

This is the outcome:

```
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into product (availability, brand, description, name, price, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into product (availability, brand, description, name, price, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_0_, product0_.availability as availabi2_0_, product0_.brand as brand3_0_, product0_.description as descript4_0_, product0_.name as name5_0_, product0_.price as price6_0_ from product product0_

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Saving works fine.Objects are properly persisted into the mysql database[image]

Here are the final lines of the mariadb general logs:

```
           86 Query insert into product (availability, brand, description, name, price, id) values (50, 'lorem', 'desc', 'Hook2', 2, 2)
           86 Query commit
           86 Query SET autocommit=1
           86 Query SET autocommit=0
           86 Query select product0_.id as id1_0_, product0_.availability as availabi2_0_, product0_.brand as brand3_0_, product0_.description as descript4_0_, product0_.name as name5_0_, product0_.price as price6_0_ from product product0_
           86 Query rollback
           86 Query SET autocommit=1
           86 Quit  
           87 Quit  
           88 Quit  
           89 Quit  
           90 Quit  
           91 Quit  
           92 Quit  
           93 Quit  
           94 Quit  
           95 Quit
```

.count works fine, however, I can't read any data back from the database. I tried doing it without the Entity abstraction and it worked just fine.